# Set dynamic id with $index

Tags: html, angularjs, indexing, parent

I've got this code:

My list, wich should work like a navigation with main nav points and sub nav poins:

```
list = [
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: 'Main 1',
        Items: [
            {
                Id: 1,
                Name: 'Sub 1'
            },
            {
                Id: 2,
                Name: 'Sub 2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Main 2',
        Items: [
            {
                Id: 1,
                Name: 'Sub 1'
            },
            {
                Id: 2,
                Name: 'Sub 2'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

And this is my HTML. I loop the main poins and it's sub points with ng-repeat and try to set some id's dynamicly with the `$index`.:

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div id="main_{{$index}}">{{item.Name}}</div>
    <div id="main_{{$parent.$index}}_sub_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="sub in item.Items">
        <div>&mdash; {{sub.Name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My result is something like this and it works fine:

```
Main 1
- Sub 1
- Sub 2
Main 2
- Sub 1
- Sub 2
```

My goal is now to assign a `id` to my `div` with the main and my `div` with the subs. I add the current index with `$index` to my id in the main `div` and after that I try to combine the id for the sub divs with the index from the main (it's parent) and the current index. To get the index of the parent, I used `$parent.$index`. My expected result are follow id's:

```
Main 1 -> id = main_0
- Sub 1 -> id = main_0_sub_0
- Sub 2 -> id = main_0_sub_1
Main 2 -> id = main_1
- Sub 1 -> id = main_1_sub_0
- Sub 2 -> id = main_1_sub_1
```

But this doesn't work at the moment. The id's for the main div is correct, but the id for the sub isn't. I thought with $parent.$index it should work, but there is a problem with the current index of the main. I have no idea how to solve this. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Your code works fine, the only thing is that you've lost closing `"` in the inner ng-repeat

https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/27954/

Comment: @GudzDaniel O dear, what a mistake, thanks sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code snippet, it's working fine here !

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('Ctrl',function($scope){
  
$scope.list = [
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: 'Main 1',
        Items: [
            {
                Id: 1,
                Name: 'Sub 1'
            },
            {
                Id: 2,
                Name: 'Sub 2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Main 2',
        Items: [
            {
                Id: 1,
                Name: 'Sub 1'
            },
            {
                Id: 2,
                Name: 'Sub 2'
            }
        ]
    }
];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<div class="wrapper" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div id="main_{{$index}}">{{item.Name}} - main_{{$index}}</div>
    <div id="main_{{$parent.$index}}_sub_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="sub in item.Items">
        <div>&mdash; {{sub.Name}} - main_{{$parent.$index}}_sub_{{$index}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that what you want is have the $index-1. Try this:

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div id="main_{{$index-1}}">{{item.Name}}</div>
    <div id="main_{{$parent.$index-1}}_sub_{{$index-1}}" ng-repeat="sub in item.Items>
        <div>&mdash; {{sub.Name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```